# Html Agility Pack, iteration on table node not working

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have the following code which should iterate through all the `<td>`'s in just one table (the fourth one on the page).

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Skip(4).Take(1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(table.SelectNodes("//table").Count()); // = 5?
                Console.WriteLine(table.SelectNodes("//table").Skip(4).Take(1).Count()); // = 1!

                foreach (var td in table.SelectNodes("//td"))
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
                }
            }
```

For some reason `table.SelectNodes("//td")` is iterating through ALL five tables `<td>`'s.

Any ideas how I can correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to make it recognized as relative path (in this case, relative to current `table`) :

```
foreach (var td in table.SelectNodes(".//td"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I will remember this for the for future reference - thank you.