# How to avoid repeatition of data extracted from a HTML source using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, extract, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to extract data from a HTML Code source.
This is an example of the HTML:

```
<div class="enum-container">
    <div class="enum">
        <span class="field-key">MD5</span> a4188cf2b9189f82b855350233a307eb
    </div>
    <div class="enum">
        <span class="field-key">SHA1</span> c3eedd67a14810b8c639eb77ed2731e574245b2a
    </div>
    <div class="enum">
        <span class="field-key">File size</span>
        3.8 KB ( 3854 bytes )
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this code:

```
    Dim Table2 As New DataTable()
    Table2.Columns.Add("Value1", GetType(String))
    Table2.Columns.Add("Value2", GetType(String))

    For Each row1 As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='file-details']//div[@class='enum-container']//div[@class='enum']")
        Dim MyValue1 As HtmlNode = row1.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='field-key']")
        Dim MyValue2 As String = row1.InnerText
        Table2.Rows.Add(MyValue1.InnerText, MyValue2)
    Next

    DataGridView3.DataSource = Table2
```

**The result is like this:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPriY.png

You can see, that the first column gets a repeated value (**MD5**).

---

**What I want is like this:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlsk5.png

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html Agility Pack, iteration on table node not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176173/html-agility-pack-iteration-on-table-node-not-working)

Comment: @har07 I used this before. I always get **MD5** as value in all rows of my table.

Comment: @Tajrib Remove the // from where you select the span. You are selecting the first span in the document that matches. That is why you are getting the same node every time

Comment: @Brian I removed // of span, and I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the first span in the document that matches in the document with the '//' xpath. You need to remove that from your xpath so it will select the direct decedents instead.

**C#**

```
DataTable fileDetailsTable = new DataTable();
fileDetailsTable.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
fileDetailsTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

HtmlNodeCollection enumNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='file-details']//div[@class='enum-container']//div[@class='enum']");
foreach (HtmlNode enumNode in enumNodes)
{
    //Select the child span from the enum node.
    HtmlNode fieldKeyNode = enumNode.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='field-key']");

    if (fieldKeyNode != null)
    {
        //Grab the key.
        string fieldKey = fieldKeyNode.InnerText;

        //Grab the value which is the field key's sibling
        string fieldValue = fieldKeyNode.NextSibling.InnerText;

        fileDetailsTable.Rows.Add(fieldKey, fieldValue);
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim fileDetailsTable As New DataTable()
fileDetailsTable.Columns.Add("Key", GetType(String))
fileDetailsTable.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))

Dim enumNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='file-details']//div[@class='enum-container']//div[@class='enum']")
For Each enumNode As HtmlNode In enumNodes
    'Select the child span from the enum node.
    Dim fieldKeyNode As HtmlNode = enumNode.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='field-key']")

    If fieldKeyNode IsNot Nothing Then
        'Grab the key.
        Dim fieldKey As String = fieldKeyNode.InnerText

        'Grab the value which is the field key's sibling
        Dim fieldValue As String = fieldKeyNode.NextSibling.InnerText

        fileDetailsTable.Rows.Add(fieldKey, fieldValue)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It works very good.
I will remember this for the for future.
Thank you so much.